# Setting the rows to variables in Tkinter

Tags: python, grid, tkinter

I cannot update the rows in Tkinter.

If I set the rows to a regular variable it doesn't not update. this is shown in the first script. 
If I set the rows to the IntVar type like you would do with text it refuses the data type. This is shown in the second script.

2 things to note:
If you watch the counter in script 1, its going up just fine but its not being applied.
If you use self.activeRow.get() instead of self.activeRow it will effectively turn  it into a normal variable with the same results shown in script 1.

Script 1

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):

    def move(self):
        self.activeRow += 1
        print(self.activeRow)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=0)      
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=0)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=0) 
        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=0)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=0)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=0)

        Label(self, text= 'row 0').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(self, text= 'row 1').grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self, text= 'row 2').grid(row=2, column=0)

        #regular variable
        self.activeRow = 0
        b = Button(self, text="normal variable {0}".format(self.activeRow), command=self.move)
        b.grid(row=self.activeRow, column=1)


        self.pack()




def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Script 2

```
from tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):

    def move(self):
        self.activeRow.set(self.activeRow.get() + 1)
        print(self.activeRow.get())

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=0)      
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=0)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=0) 
        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=0)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=0)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=0)

        Label(self, text= 'row 0').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(self, text= 'row 1').grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self, text= 'row 2').grid(row=2, column=0)

        #Tkinter IntVar
        self.activeRow = IntVar()
        self.activeRow.set(0)


        b = Button(self, text="IntVar", command=self.move)
        b.grid(row=self.activeRow, column=1)


        self.pack()
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example? `row=self.activeRow` should work, provided that `self` has a value set for `activeRow`.

Comment: Ok, I just rewrote it with more detail.

and if my formatting/style is off, pls let me know because I only started to learn how to program 6 weeks ago.

Comment: Oh and just to save you re-reading it the problem is:
If self.activeRow is a normal variable it doesnt update, and if its an IntVar then it isnt accepted because its not an int. So how else can i make it change rows?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is very unclear. What does "update the rows" mean? What do you mean by "doesn't update"? *what* doesn't update? Do you want the button label to change to "normal variable 1", "normal variable 2", etc as you press it? Or do you want the labels in the other rows to change? If you want the labels to change, what do you want them to change to?

Comment: Fabien Andre answered it. If your still wondering out of curiosity, copy past his code and hit the button. You will see it move down a row each time. That was what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move an existing widget, you have to call again the `grid` method to update this widget (ie `widget.grid(row=other_value)`). To remove a widget, you can use the `grid_forget()` method.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def move(self):
        info = self.b.grid_info()
        previous_row = int(info["row"]) #int() needed because datas are stored as string
        self.b.grid(row=previous_row+1)

    def initUI(self):
        for i in range(5):
            l = Label(self, text="Row {0}".format(i))
            l.grid(row=i, column=0)

        self.b =  Button(self, text="Moving button", command=self.move)
        self.b.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.pack()

root = Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are a god amongst men! Thanks so much, I can finally get back to my assignment!

Answer (score 0):

You may use either a regular python variable or a Tkinter variable. Below are two working examples.

Tkinter variables classes are variables which changes can be "traced" (ie you may be notified that values have changed). They are used with widgets with values (Scale, Entry...) for instance to retrieve values, or to sync two widgets.

```
def initUI(self):
    #regular variable
    self.activeRow = 0
    for i in range(5):
        b = Button(self, text="normal variable {0}".format(self.activeRow))
        b.grid(row=self.activeRow, column=0)
        self.activeRow += 1

    #Tkinter IntVar
    self.activeRow = IntVar()
    for i in range (5):
        b = Button(self, text="IntVar {0}".format(self.activeRow.get()))
        b.grid(row=self.activeRow.get(), column=1)
        self.activeRow.set(self.activeRow.get() + 1)
```

Comment: Ok, just updated my original post and wrote 2 scripts to better explain the problem. Your 2 modifications do run, but they don't actually involve any updating because the change comes from the for loop and is there from the start. The correct updating is what I'm trying to figure ou

Comment: OK, ultimately catch your question, I post another answer.